# M Query to find and extract strings of numbers with a specific digit count from a random position in a string

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, data-cleaning, m

I've found answers to similar questions and tried to adapt them to my circumstance, but nothing has worked for me. I've tried to "translate" my existing and working Excel formula, but couldn't manage and copilot has been worse than useless.

In PowerBI, I need to add a column that finds a 13 digit number in another column and extracts that. The number can be anywhere in the string and is not reliably delimited by any characters. It can also be one of several numbers, but the only 13 digit one.

The closest I've come so far (that is, the only thing that has worked somewhat) is:

```
= if Text.Length(Text.Select(Text.From([campaign_name]),{"0".."9"}))=13 then Text.Select(Text.From([campaign_name]),{"0".."9"}) else null
```

But unfortunately, this will only work if there are no additional numbers in the string beyond the 13 digit one.

In a second scenario I also need to find any 15+ digit numbers and then only use the left 15 digits of that, but first things first.

Can someone help me out?

Sample Data:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
let 
a = Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"})([Column]),
b = List.Transform(a, each Text.Start(_,13)),
c = List.Transform(b, (x)=> if Text.Length(x) = 13 and Value.Is(Value.FromText(x), type number) then x else null),
d = List.RemoveNulls(c){0}?
in d
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. For my purposes, especially for the second scenario, it works. Though I should mention this will extract the first n characters from a >=n digit number string, so it would fail at identifying numbers with =n digits (and not longer).

Comment: Not sure I follow. Can you paste an example where it fails?

Comment: I mean in this configuration if there's a number with, say, 20 digits, it will extract the first 13 digits of that number. So if it should take only numbers with exactly 13 digits, it would fail to do so if there are longer numbers present. Right now it's >= as opposed to =. Which works for me, but isn't =13.

Comment: Understood. Yes, that would be a different approach required.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regex **[0-9]{13}** to find 13 digits using home...advanced editor... to paste in the second row manually

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Regex=(text,regex)=> Web.Page( "<script> var x='"&text&"'; var y=new RegExp('"&regex&"','g');  var b=x.match(y);   document.write(b);  </script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0} ,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Output", each Regex([Column1], "[0-9]{13}"))
in  #"Added Custom"
```

[image]